# Spring mvc::why my web app is not thead safe

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, thread-safety

I'm working on an open source projet and i have issues with my application.

- When multiple users use the app, one users can get another one's data ( the server response).
  my beans are request and session scoped and my controller request scoped.
- When starting tomcat, beans are created 3x times.

I've read lot of documentations and try playing with scopes and nothing.
I must be missing something. Thanks for your help.

My controller:.

```
@Controller    
@Scope("request")    
public class SpinalToolboxWebController {

    @Autowired
    private FileOperationsService fileOperationsService;

    @Autowired
    private ServerResponse serverResponse;

    @Autowired
    private SoftwareCommunicationService softwareCommunicationService;

    @Autowired
    private StringBuffer stringBuffer;

    @Autowired
    private UserEnvironmentService userEnvironmentService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")    
    public ModelAndView home(){

        System.out.println("Passing throught home controller");

        return new ModelAndView(SpinalToolBoxWebConstants.VIEW_HOME, "result", "command submitted : ");

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json")
    public  @ResponseBody
            ServerResponse handleUploadedFiles(@RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file,
                                                      @RequestParam(value="token") String token)throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Passing throught upload controller");    
        if(!fileOperationsService.isUploadedFileExtensionAllowed(file.getOriginalFilename()))
        {
            serverResponse.setUndefinedResponse();
            return serverResponse;
        }

        if(fileOperationsService.uploadFile(file, token)){
            serverResponse.setResponse(file, softwareCommunicationService.generateRawAndHeader(file));
        }
        else{
            serverResponse.setUndefinedResponse();
        }
        return serverResponse;

    }
}
```

Here is my java config file:

```
@Configuration    
public class SpinalToolBoxWebConfig {

    @Value("${uploadPath}") private String uploadPathFromPropertyFile;

    //Resolve view name to jsp

    @Bean
    ViewResolver viewResolver(){

        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();    
        resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/view/");    
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");   
        /*resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);    
        resolver.setExposedContextBeanNames("configProperties");*/    
        return resolver;    
    }


    @Bean    
    @Scope("request")    
    @ScopedProxy    
    public FileOperationsController fileOperationsController(){    
        return new FileOperationsController();    
    }

    @Bean    
    @Scope("request")    
    @ScopedProxy    
    public LogController logController() {return new LogController();}

    @Bean    
    @Scope("request")    
    @ScopedProxy    
    public ServerResponse serverResponse(){return new ServerResponse();}

    @Bean    
    @Scope("request")    
    @ScopedProxy    
    public SoftwareCommunicationController softwareCommunicationController() {return new SoftwareCommunicationController();}

    @Bean    
    @Scope("prototype")    
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() throws java.io.IOException{    
        Resource fileSystemResource = new FileSystemResource(uploadPathFromPropertyFile);    
        System.out.println(uploadPathFromPropertyFile);    
        CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();    
        commonsMultipartResolver.setUploadTempDir(fileSystemResource);    
        commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(-1); //no limit to file upload size

        return commonsMultipartResolver;

    }

    @Bean    
    @Scope("request")    
    @ScopedProxy    
    public StringBuffer stringBuffer(){ return new StringBuffer();}

    @Bean    
    @Scope("session")    
    @ScopedProxy    
    public UserEnvironment userEnvironment(){    
        return new UserEnvironment();    
    }

    @Bean    
    @Scope("request")    
    @ScopedProxy    
    public UserEnvironmentController userEnvironmentController(){return new UserEnvironmentController(); }

}
```

Here is my servlet-context.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">


    <util:properties id="configProperties" location="WEB-INF/config.properties" />

    <context:property-placeholder  properties-ref="configProperties" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="spinalToolBoxWeb"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="${resources}" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/external/**" location="file:///${uploadPath}" />    

</beans>
```

Here is my web xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"

         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">



    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spinalToolBoxServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/spinalToolBoxServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spinalToolBoxServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener> </web-app>
```

Comment: First thing I noticed is that you have Controllers annotated as Request scope. Are you sure this is what you want? Unless you have a good reason, you should leave the controllers in Singleton scope. Actually I would leave everything in Singleton scope apart from the UserEnvironment.

Comment: @Imazgon if everything is in Singleton scope, there will be just one instance and all users will share the same bean. right? From what i understood, singleton are instancied once. so, if my controller is in singleton, it will reference the same beans for all users.

Comment: Yeah that's right. That means that you can't save any data in instance variables of the Controller, because the instance of the Controller is shared. But you could have a service to retrieve the UserEnvironment for this exact user, based on his ID, and work with his data.

Comment: I guess you have worked with EJB in the past, based on the style of your code? You should look into tutorials about Spring and learn how to structure a Spring project - get to know the /@Controller, /@Service, /@Repository annotations. All these are (by default) Singletons and you should leave them like that. They don't save the state of a users request/session, but rather the state of the whole application. So if you want to save user data between requests, save it in the Session or to the Database. Of course there are other ways, but these are the simplest.

Comment: @Imazgon if your controller is a singleton, everything is fine with the first user. but if the second user connects while the first user is still there, this same controller will refers to the instanciated beans of the first users. that's why my controller is request scoped. may be i'm wrong... can you tell me where it can be a problem?

Comment: @Imazgon nice guess. i've worked with EJB :) i've read tutorials on spring annotation and aop-proxy. do you have an idea why beans are created many times when i start tomcat ?

Comment: There is no need to worry about this, because there will be *no user specific data* inside the controller. I recommend that you take the time and watch this presentation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tEm0USdF-70

Comment: I realized that maybe the presentation is a bit too advanced. Anyway, you should google "Spring MVC tutorial" or something similar. For example here is the tutorial from Spring http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/

Comment: Just like any other servlets, your controller should have a single instance, and the container will run each request on a separate thread. You should not be using instance variable inside the Controller/ Servlet. If it's user specific, store them in session.

Comment: @Imazgon thanks for the links. it helps understanding spring more.

Comment: @Imazgon  i'll put my controller as singleton. my question now is how to reference my services in my method since i dont want to have the object to be shared.

Comment: @Sas  i'll put my controller as singleton. my question now is how to reference my services in my method since i dont want to have the object to be shared.

Comment: You can store them in session object, so it will not be shared among users. to set: request.getSession(false).setAttribute("myservice",service); to get: request.getSession(false).getAttribute("myservice");